# How to add table view cell to tableview in xib?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, xib

I am in need to create custom alert with table view. So I created seperate xib file. In this xib file I have added table view to view. But I am not able to add table view cell to table view. Can anyone please help me to do it.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Like In StoryBoard You can't Add Tableview cell Directly to TableView in Xib.

You have to Create Separate XIB File For TableView Cell and register the cell with tableview through programatically with Below Code.

```
self.tableView.register(YourTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in IB :

- for tableview select Content : Static Cells
- set number of sections
- set number of row in each sections